# Start a process not as a child

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

I need to start a process and run it as a detached process. I have some sort of starter application which purpose is to run another exe and immediately exit. What is a best way to achieve that?

I read [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation several times but still have questions. Documentation says that I need to call `CloseHandle` after I finish. But my parent app shouldn't wait for a child to exit. Another part of documentation says that I can leave handles alone - the system will close them when the parent process terminates. Does that means that child application exits immediately after parent? It seems not true - I close a starter but my child process still runs.

There's a `DETACHED_PROCESS` flag that seem what I'm looking for. But documentation says something about console. What console? I don't care about console.

Comment: Calling `CloseHandle` on a process handle does not terminate the process. It just closes your handle to the process object. The process object still exists, and will continue on its way. So, call `CreateProcess`, and then terminate your launcher process. Call `CloseHandle` on the two handles if you wish. Or not, and the system will tidy them up for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[DETACHED_PROCESS flag documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states

> For console processes, the **new process does not inherit its parent's console (the default)**

that means: if you have a console process and you start a new one, it will not inherit its parent's console.

If you don't have a console process you don't have to worry about it.

[CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) creates a child process but **does not wait for the child process to finish**, so you're already all set.

If you wanted to **wait** for the child process to complete, you should have called `CreateProcess` and then `WaitForSingleObject`

To summarize:

```
// Version 1) Launch and wait for a child process completion
STARTUPINFO info = { sizeof(info) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
if (CreateProcess(L"C:\\myapp.exe", L"", NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo)) {
    ::WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE); // DO WAIT for the child to exit
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------

// Version 2) Launch and do NOT wait for a child process completion
STARTUPINFO info = { sizeof(info) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
if (CreateProcess(L"C:\\myapp.exe", L"", NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo)) {
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess); // Cleanup since you don't need this
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread); // Cleanup since you don't need this
}
```

notice that version 2 will **not** terminate your child process. Only resources which are no longer needed will be released.

Comment: Oh, I thought that closing a handle means closing an app...  And what if starter exits but child will write to it's console (assuming we didn't specify a flag)? I'm using gui app as child so I can't check.

Comment: @nikitablacka a win32 app won't use a console subsystem. No problems in that case either.

Answer (score 5):

> I read CreateProcess documentation several times but still have questions. Documentation says that I need to call CloseHandle after I finish. But my parent app shouldn't wait for a child to exit.

Okay, then don't wait. You can call `CloseHandle` immediately in the parent.

> Another part of documentation says that I can leave handles alone - the system will close them when the parent process terminates. Does that means that child application exits immediately after parent? It seems not true - I close a starter but my child process still runs.

No, it doesn't. I'm not sure how you got that from the documentation, but that's not what it means.

> There's a DETACHED_PROCESS flag that seem what I'm looking for. But documentation says something about console. What console? I don't care about console.

If you don't care, then don't worry about it.