# Call a console application without waiting for it

Tags: c#, delphi

I'm developing a Delphi application which calls a .net console application in hide mode, but the problem is: when I close my delphi application then the console application also closes, even using ShellExecute without specifying to wait for a SingleObject.

I tried that same Shell call for Windows Calc, so now even when I close my app the Calc remains opened and that is the behavior that I'm looking for.

Does someone know if it's possible to call a console application and leave it independent from parent process and how to do that, so it does not close when main application closes?

Comment: Can you show your code that runs the second application?

Comment: ShellExecute ( Application.Handle, 'open', PChar ( 'my console app path' ), PChar ( Parameters ), Nil, 1 );

Comment: Without knowing much about Delphi, try passing `nil` instead of your application's handle as a parent window.

Comment: @Blindy Why would that help? You don't need to know anything about delphi to know how the ShellExecute winapi function works. That's just the owner window for any dialogs that are show. Since no dialogs are show it doesn't much matter what is passed

Comment: I've already done it, i also imagined that it might be a handle, but after a quick test it continues with the same behavior.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29899643/3164070

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that the child process attaches to the console of the parent process. When the parent closes, it's console closes, taking the child with it.

Resolve this by giving the child process its own console. Use `CreateProcess` passing the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` process creation flag. You will also want to pass `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` to avoid showing the new console window.

Comment: CreateProcess(nil, Addr(ProgramName[1]), nil, nil, false,
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE , nil, Addr(WorkDir[1]),
    StartInfo, ProcInfo) is it?

Comment: Then it seems likely that the issue lies in the console application, or that the two processes are part of a job object. Try with a different console app. Try `cmd /c`

Comment: Every console app that i've tried fell off into the same problem, only visual applications respect this parameters

Comment: Sorry, I got that wrong, you can use plain `cmd` to test this, the `/c` argument is wrong, it forces the cmd process to close.

Comment: David i've tried but the console application still closes after i close
the main application in delphi.

If you try with cmd, you'll notice this behavior

Comment: Works fine here.

Comment: David Heffernan i figured out the problem, if i run inside IDE and stop execution then the 2 process are killed, however if run outside IDE it does not happen.

I didn't realize before because this behavior does not 
occurs when you execute a Calc for example. I really don't  know why this behavior.

So the problem was solved, thank you so much!